# Find string inside of an anchor tag from cURL response using bash

Tags: bash, curl

I am working on a small project that will scan about 6,000 url's and tell me which ones have links to my website and if they are marked `rel=no-follow` I am working on backlink cleanup. I need to basically search the html returned by cURL for a string and if it finds it I need it to echo it to a file. Right now the issue is that I am getting some errors:

```
./checkURL.sh: line 4: syntax error in conditional expression
./checkURL.sh: line 5: syntax error near `then'
./checkURL.sh: line 5: `then'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
test="curl https://example.com"
result=$(eval "$test")
if [[ $result == *turtles*]]
then
    echo "its there";
fi
```

I pulled the example of the if statement from another stackoverflow question and it appeared to work for the OP doing the same thing as me so I am not sure what went wrong in my code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space:

```
if [[ $result == *turtles*]]
                          ^
                          |
--------------------------
```

Comment: WOW! that was easy haha im use to non strict languages like php